# Is there a way to set the level of compression when using System.IO.Compression.GZipStream

Tags: .net, compression

Is it possible to set compression level when using .NET's `GZipStream` to compress a stream?  It seems that Ionic Zip has a constructor for this, but I would rather not use a library just to get this feature.

Comment: No.  The internal GZipFormatter class has a constructor that takes a compression level argument.  But it doesn't actually use it.  Not implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of .NET 4.5, the `CompressionLevel` enum has been added to a couple constructors for `GZipStream`.

The options are:

```
CompressionLevel.Optimal = 0
CompressionLevel.Fastest = 1
CompressionLevel.NoCompression = 2
```

So, you can now create a `GZipStream` by passing a `CompressionLevel` which determines how much to compress the data.

```
using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
{
    // ...
}
```

More information is available in the [`GZipStream` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.5) or the [`CompressionLevel` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.compressionlevel?view=netframework-4.5).

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't go so far as to say it's impossible, but based on my review of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) I would say it's definitely not supported out of the box.

I think their excuse for this is summed up by:

> Data is read in on a byte-by-byte
>   basis, so it is not possible to
>   perform multiple passes to determine
>   the best method for compressing entire
>   files or large blocks of data.

[This posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/93b3631f-4cb6-4b24-aaa3-542e00c0b068/) says that internally it defaults to level 3, and that it has options (again, internally) to support changing the level of compression, but that it isn't exposed.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code here:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/sys/System/IO/compression/GZipStream.cs,b228c3ce72d4d124

```
        // Implies mode = Compress
    public GZipStream(Stream stream, CompressionLevel compressionLevel)

        : this(stream, compressionLevel, false) {
    }


    // Implies mode = Compress
    public GZipStream(Stream stream, CompressionLevel compressionLevel, bool leaveOpen) {

        deflateStream = new DeflateStream(stream, compressionLevel, leaveOpen);
        deflateStream.SetFileFormatWriter(new GZipFormatter());
    }
```

When passing the compression level the mode is always "Compress"!